# How can I send special catacteres to Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm facing a problem when I send special caracteres to mysql database. I'm using the follow statement on the firs line on my JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I don't know why, but I'm using the same statement on creation and works perfectly and the special caracteres are sent correctly to database, but on the update doesn't works and the special caracteres are sent wrong.

Like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9wAR.png)

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks,

Thiago

Answer (score 1):

you can use escape character

\0 An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'  A single quote (“'”) character.
\"  A double quote (“"”) character.
\b  A backspace character.
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.
\r  A carriage return character.
\t  A tab character.
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control-Z). See note following the table.
\  A backslash (“\”) character.
\%  A “%” character. See note following the table.
_  A “_” character. See note following the table.

Comment: I solved the problem just deleting the statement: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>